# What purpose does the + sign serve in this code?

Tags: python, string

I just want to understand what the `+` sign does after `str(num1)` and before/after `str(num2)`

```
import random

def random_num():

    num1 = random.randint(1,20)
    num2 = random.randint(1,20)
    return num1, num2


def addition_operation():

    global correct

    num1,num2 = random_num()
    answer1 = int(input(str(num1)+" + "+str(num2)+" = "))
    if num1+num2 == answer1:
        print("Correct!")
        correct += 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

Comment: It is just adding two strings. `print("abc" + "bcd" + "cde")` will print `abcbcdcde`

Comment: it is one way  of string concatenation in python

Answer (score 0):

It concatenates (joins) strings, for example `print("a" + "b")` prints `ab`

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the + operator works on more than just integers. For example, it works on lists, tuples, and in this case, strings. What the plus is doing is combining num1 as a string (so for example, if `num1 = 16` then `str(num1) = "16"`) with `" + "` to get a new string: `16 +`.